# CATransform3D perspective not working on CATransformLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, catransform3d, catransform3drotate

**Note : Please ignore colors, gradients and size! My concern is perspective is not worked as expected**

I am trying to achieve output as bellow,

[image]

But when I run my code it is giving me following output

[image]

Have a look at my code please :

```
CATransformLayer *baseLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
baseLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
baseLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds;
baseLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));

[self.view.layer addSublayer:baseLayer];

CALayer *redLayer = [CALayer layer];
redLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
redLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
redLayer.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
redLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5); // right
[baseLayer addSublayer:redLayer];

CALayer *blueLayer = [CALayer layer];
blueLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
blueLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 100);
blueLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5); // right
blueLayer.position = CGPointMake(-50,0);
[baseLayer addSublayer:blueLayer];

CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = -1/80;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0);
blueLayer.transform = transform;

baseLayer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, degreesToRadians(80), 0, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't what makes this issue resolved but here is my updated code it is working as expected.

```
CATransformLayer *baseLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
baseLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
baseLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds;
baseLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));

CALayer *redLayer = [CALayer layer];
redLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
redLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 250);
redLayer.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
redLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5); // right
redLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, M_PI_2,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
[baseLayer addSublayer:redLayer];

CALayer *blueLayer = [CALayer layer];
blueLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
blueLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 250);
blueLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5); // right
blueLayer.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
[baseLayer addSublayer:blueLayer];

CGFloat perspective = -1000.0; //This relates to the m34 perspective matrix.

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / perspective;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(newTransform, degreesToRadians(10) , 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


baseLayer.sublayerTransform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

Comment: The problem was that, in C, the expression `1/80` is performed as integer division, and produces `0`. When you changed it to `1/perspective`, where `perspective` has type `CGFloat`, you made it use floating-point division, which produces a fractional, non-zero result.